# Sagemaker instance does automatic cd at startup

Tags: shell, command-line, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Sagemaker instance that's linked to a github repo `my-repo`, and every time I open a new terminal, I see this immediately at startup:

```
sh-4.2$ cd "my-repo"
sh: cd: my-repo: No such file or directory
```

I assumed something was in the .bashrc or .bash_profile that prompted this (failed) `cd` but it's not in there. Any ideas where I should look for what's causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not specific to SageMaker Notebook instances. Rather, it is a bug in the Git extension of JupyterLab. You can find details around this here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/issues/346

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question. Will leave it up for anyone similarly perplexed. In Sagemaker, you have two ways of opening a new terminal: 
`File > New > Terminal`
and 
`Git > Open Terminal`.
The latter automatically tries to `cd` into your linked repo. The end.